# Is Ubuntu's Gnome being updated?

Tags: 12.04, gnome

What I'm wondering is this - is Ubuntu-native Gnome being updated?

I'm asking because I notice a discrepancy - Unity had a problem before in the new mail indicator staying blue if you read the message directly in Thunderbird when it arrives instead of via clicking the indicator itself.

This has been fixed in 12.04 from what I've noticed.

But transitioning to Gnome returned this issue. Will this fix be applied to Gnome too, or has Gnome been abandoned in terms of staying up to date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use GNOME Shell or GNOME Fallback ("GNOME Classic") in Ubuntu, they are supported by the community rather than by Canonical, but they updated under [the same circumstances under which Unity (and Unity 2D) is updated](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates).

As with Unity (and Unity 2D), GNOME Shell and GNOME Fallback can get big changes including new features with each subsequent release of Ubuntu (though GNOME Fallback might not ever change much). Each stable release of Ubuntu ships with the versions of software that are [stable in Ubuntu in time for them to be included](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FeatureFreeze).

**As for the specific mail indicator problem you're experiencing, you should [report this as a bug](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs).**

Comment: Thank you. I'm pretty sure I saw this bug reported already during 11.10, in these very forums, but I'll look around again when I have time and test some more before I go an report it. Thanks for the valuable information.

Comment: The second one is what I'm doing, just until I see if anyone else has anything to add on that indicator bug.